# Invalidate iOS device push token on user logout

Tags: ios, rest, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How do I reliably invalidate (remove from the users profile on my server) a device's push token for a users of my service when they log out of my app?

I keep an array of strings containing apns tokens on my user profiles, adding one whenever the user enables push notifications on a given device.

Later I realized the push token is unique to the device, but obviously knows nothing of my internal user accounts, so if one user logs out and another logs in (same device) they each have the same token. Then the current user of the device gets push notifications directed for either of them.

The basic solution is to remove a device's token from the user profile on logout, but I'm coming up with a bunch of gotchas as I think that through:

1. Logout should not *require* network access – I can try to notify my server, but need logout to succeed asynchronously even if the user does not have network access (?)
2. The actual device-token might be unknown – if the user has temporarily shut off push permission then the current token is not given. And storing device<->key info seems tenuous at best since identifierForVendor changes per install and UDID methods are deprecated.
3. Do server side uniquing (on adding a token to an account, make sure the same token is not set for any other accounts) – this depends on a second user logging in, which is not guaranteed.

Are there more edge cases I'm missing and what strategies can I use to work around them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your gotcha's do present some of the difficult situations you may face. I would recommend you shift or make sure that the push-sending logic is entirely on the server-side: link a pushtoken to a user identifier of your choice (meaning one push token could be linked to several users indeed). This identifier that you control is to be the account identifier that is targeted when you need to send a push. This way, you can control which user is supposed to receive a notification and retrieve his pushtoken based on this identifier (vs any device identifier provided by Apple which assumes that 1 device = 1 user).

In the event that your user logs out offline, you will not know about it. You might send that user a notification. If the user chooses to act on it, your app will open and you can, at that point, unsubscribe the user identifier from your server (since he's obviously online at this point).

Comment: Not sure I follow the first paragraph. I essentially have the first half (one token can be linked to multiple users) already, but am not sure how I would differentiate which user it is valid for. Maybe something like a timestamp of when it was first saved to that user profile, thus the latest would be the valid one?

Comment: Thanks for the point about reacting to offline-logout followed by push notification, that does seem like the best case solution given the API, and alleviates my qualms about caveat one.

Comment: About the first paragraph, when you store the pushtoken on your server, you can send the user identifer at the same time. Your server will know at this point if the user is valid or not, no?

Although I'm not sure I understood your question correctly... the pushtoken will be the same, regardless of the timestamp at which it was generated; not sure I follow your idea.

Comment: Yes - push userid is explicitly (json) & inherently (auth) attached to the token being pushed; I think we are leaning toward storing tokens uniquely and associating them with the latest user to submit, then the only gap is 'silent logouts' which should be infrequent and can be warned against or cleaned up.

Comment: We are basically taking the approach described, and using background fetch as an additional cleanup mechanism.

Comment: If you associate a unique token with the last user to submit it, you are effectively saying that a logged out user will not receive any push notifications. If that's your choice by design, that's fine. However, and this completely depends on your app and what it does, sending a push to a user who is logged out is great for re-engagement and your code should be able to detect that the user logged in != the user receiving push and force the current use to log out and invite the other one to log in. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Crap. A very good point indeed. Handling the logout flow pus login for the previous user wasn't even in my realm of consideration. Handling the re-login flow if somebody desires pushes but not being permanently logged in is just a sub case of that (also worth considering). Thanks for all the insight.

Comment: I'm currently facing the same problem. Did you come up with a good solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

1. when your app runs for the first time on a device generate an uuid (Universally unique id) and save this on device using NSUserDefaults

   NSString *uuid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"app_uuid"];

   ```
   if(uuid == nil){
       uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:uuid forKey:@"app_uuid"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

   }
   ```

   this uuid will be used to identify unique application instance a user is using and logged in to (if you want the user to be able to login to multiple devices with same user id).
2. then every time you send token to your server, send user id and app uuid with it. and on server side check if app uuid already exist, if yes overwrite the tuple with new token and user id and if no create and save new tuple with user id, token, and uuid.
3. when sending notification to a specific user get all the tuples with user id, get the tokens from them and send notification using these token.